# Postgres choosing a filter instead of index cond when OR is involved

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-performance

I have a table that daily gets about 20 million records added to it, and I'm trying to paginate through it to let people get access to all the data in it, but the query time has to be "decent" (in my case defined as less than 30s/query).

To do this I've been using keyset pagination in the past but for this particular query and table I've gotten some really slow query times, and it seems to be because the query planner decides to filter out a day's worth of data and then run a filter on it instead of an index condition scan.

The table looks like this:

```
create table mmsi_positions_archive
(
    id bigserial not null
        constraint mmsi_positions_archive_pkey
            primary key,
    position_id uuid,
    previous_id uuid,
    mmsi bigint not null,
    collection_type varchar not null,
    accuracy numeric,
    maneuver numeric,
    rate_of_turn numeric,
    status integer,
    speed numeric,
    course numeric,
    heading numeric,
    position geometry(Point,4326),
    timestamp timestamp with time zone not null,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone default now(),
    created_at timestamp with time zone default now()
);

create index ix_mmsi_positions_archive_mmsi
    on mmsi_positions_archive (mmsi);

create index ix_mmsi_positions_archive_position_id
    on mmsi_positions_archive (position_id);

create index ix_mmsi_positions_archive_timestamp_mmsi_id_asc
    on mmsi_positions_archive (timestamp, id);
```

The column I'm trying to paginate by is the `timestamp` and `id`, to help out I've also updated the table statistics target for `timestamp` and set it to the max value of 10 000 and analyzed the table.

The table is also partitioned by quarter, but at the moment I'm only operating on the data for a single partition.

**Fast query**

```
SELECT id
FROM mmsi_positions_archive
WHERE timestamp > '2019-03-10 00:00:00.000000+00:00'
  AND timestamp <= '2019-03-11 00:00:00+00:00'
ORDER BY timestamp, id
LIMIT 100
```

Which gives the following query plan (note that the `mmsi_positions_archive` table itself is empty, all the data is in the `*_p2019_q1` table):

```
Limit  (cost=0.60..5.39 rows=100 width=16) (actual time=0.053..0.089 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Merge Append  (cost=0.60..773572.19 rows=16149157 width=16) (actual time=0.053..0.082 rows=100 loops=1)
"        Sort Key: mmsi_positions_archive.""timestamp"", mmsi_positions_archive.id"
        ->  Sort  (cost=0.01..0.02 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
"              Sort Key: mmsi_positions_archive.""timestamp"", mmsi_positions_archive.id"
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Seq Scan on mmsi_positions_archive  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Filter: (("timestamp" > '2019-03-10 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" <= '2019-03-11 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
        ->  Index Only Scan using mmsi_positions_archive_p2019q1_timestamp_id_index on mmsi_positions_archive_p2019q1  (cost=0.58..571707.70 rows=16149156 width=16) (actual time=0.043..0.067 rows=100 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (("timestamp" > '2019-03-10 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" <= '2019-03-11 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
              Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 67.023 ms
Execution time: 0.128 ms
```

**Keyset pagination query (slow)**

```
SELECT id
FROM mmsi_positions_archive
WHERE (timestamp > '2019-03-10 00:00:00.000000+00:00'
           OR (timestamp = '2019-03-10 00:00:00.000000+00:00' AND id >  1032749689))
  AND timestamp <= '2019-03-11 00:00:00+00:00'
ORDER BY timestamp, id
LIMIT 100
```

Which gives this explain, which ends up running much slower:

```
Limit  (cost=0.60..25.08 rows=100 width=16) (actual time=332918.152..332918.192 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Merge Append  (cost=0.60..41278140.09 rows=168591751 width=16) (actual time=332918.152..332918.189 rows=100 loops=1)
"        Sort Key: mmsi_positions_archive.""timestamp"", mmsi_positions_archive.id"
        ->  Sort  (cost=0.01..0.02 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
"              Sort Key: mmsi_positions_archive.""timestamp"", mmsi_positions_archive.id"
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Seq Scan on mmsi_positions_archive  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Filter: (("timestamp" <= '2019-03-11 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (("timestamp" > '2019-03-10 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) OR (("timestamp" = '2019-03-10 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (id > 1032749689))))
        ->  Index Only Scan using mmsi_positions_archive_p2019q1_timestamp_id_index on mmsi_positions_archive_p2019q1  (cost=0.58..39170743.18 rows=168591750 width=16) (actual time=332918.147..332918.181 rows=100 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ("timestamp" <= '2019-03-11 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
              Filter: (("timestamp" > '2019-03-10 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) OR (("timestamp" = '2019-03-10 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (id > 1032749689)))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 953622052
              Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 0.778 ms
Execution time: 332918.226 ms
```

From my understanding, this ends up slower because the index condition `Index Cond: ("timestamp" <= '2019-03-11 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone` ends up doing a seq scan over ~20 million*70 rows of index data and then filtering them out.

**Workaround**

I did some testing and figured out that the problem was the `OR` in the statement; both of them gives me a fast plan if I don't `OR`. So I switched it up and made a `UNION` query to get the data I wanted:

```
SELECT id
FROM (
         SELECT *
         FROM (
                  SELECT id        AS id,
                         timestamp AS timestamp
                  FROM mmsi_positions_archive
                  WHERE timestamp = '2019-03-10 00:00:00.000000+00:00'
                    AND id > 1032749689
                  ORDER BY timestamp, id
                  LIMIT 100
              ) keyset
         UNION
         SELECT *
         FROM (
                  SELECT id        AS id,
                         timestamp AS timestamp
                  FROM mmsi_positions_archive
                  WHERE timestamp > '2019-03-10 00:00:00.000000+00:00'
                    AND timestamp <= '2019-03-11 00:00:00+00:00'
                  ORDER BY timestamp, id
                  LIMIT 100
              ) all_after
     ) archive_ids
ORDER BY timestamp, id
LIMIT 100
```

Yielding a fast query and the following query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=34.27..34.52 rows=100 width=16) (actual time=0.232..0.242 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=34.27..34.77 rows=200 width=16) (actual time=0.231..0.238 rows=100 loops=1)
"        Sort Key: mmsi_positions_archive.""timestamp"", mmsi_positions_archive.id"
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 34kB
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=22.63..24.63 rows=200 width=16) (actual time=0.151..0.167 rows=200 loops=1)
"              Group Key: mmsi_positions_archive.id, mmsi_positions_archive.""timestamp"""
              ->  Append  (cost=0.71..21.63 rows=200 width=16) (actual time=0.028..0.111 rows=200 loops=1)
                    ->  Limit  (cost=0.71..12.24 rows=100 width=16) (actual time=0.028..0.049 rows=100 loops=1)
                          ->  Merge Append  (cost=0.71..17.43 rows=145 width=16) (actual time=0.027..0.046 rows=100 loops=1)
                                Sort Key: mmsi_positions_archive.id
                                ->  Index Scan using mmsi_positions_archive_pkey on mmsi_positions_archive  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (id > 1032749689)
                                      Filter: ("timestamp" = '2019-03-10 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                                ->  Index Only Scan using mmsi_positions_archive_p2019q1_timestamp_id_index on mmsi_positions_archive_p2019q1  (cost=0.58..7.46 rows=144 width=16) (actual time=0.017..0.028 rows=100 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (("timestamp" = '2019-03-10 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (id > 1032749689))
                                      Heap Fetches: 0
                    ->  Limit  (cost=0.60..5.39 rows=100 width=16) (actual time=0.012..0.049 rows=100 loops=1)
                          ->  Merge Append  (cost=0.60..773572.19 rows=16149157 width=16) (actual time=0.011..0.044 rows=100 loops=1)
"                                Sort Key: mmsi_positions_archive_1.""timestamp"", mmsi_positions_archive_1.id"
                                ->  Sort  (cost=0.01..0.02 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
"                                      Sort Key: mmsi_positions_archive_1.""timestamp"", mmsi_positions_archive_1.id"
                                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                      ->  Seq Scan on mmsi_positions_archive mmsi_positions_archive_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
                                            Filter: (("timestamp" > '2019-03-10 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" <= '2019-03-11 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                                ->  Index Only Scan using mmsi_positions_archive_p2019q1_timestamp_id_index on mmsi_positions_archive_p2019q1 mmsi_positions_archive_p2019q1_1  (cost=0.58..571707.70 rows=16149156 width=16) (actual time=0.006..0.031 rows=100 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (("timestamp" > '2019-03-10 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" <= '2019-03-11 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                                      Heap Fetches: 0
Planning time: 1.059 ms
Execution time: 0.312 ms
```

While I'm okay to rewrite my query to use the `UNION` approach, I do wonder if there is some way to better help Postgres get the same fast results with the at-a-glance-easier-to understand query with the `OR`?

I'm also running this on AWS Aurora Postgres 9.6. I'm aware that we're a couple of major releases behind and I'm planning on upgrading ASAP, but at the moment I just need to get this thing working. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately this is very simple in PostgreSQL as it supports comparisons between “row values” (or compound values) that can make use of an index.

So you can write:

```
WHERE (timestamp, id) > ('2019-03-10 00:00:00+00:00', 1032749689)
  AND timestamp <= '2019-03-11 00:00:00+00:00'
ORDER BY timestamp, id
LIMIT 100
```

The comparison of such row values is *lexicographical*, that is exactly like you want it.

Here is a [documentation link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON) for that feature.